# Scrollbar on bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-table

I have `table` that renders inside a `panel` which is inside a `modal`. As the table is relatively large, I'd like to restrict it's rows to say 5 so that the modal does not become scrollable. I looked through SO and google and everywhere I see that I need to set the `overflow-y:auto` or `overflow-y:scroll`  to get it to work, however in my case, it does not. I also set a random height of 400px and position:absolute. This got the table to be scrollable but now the panel closes with the `<thead>` and the body of the table renders outside the panel. What's the fix to this?

**My code snippet is:**

```
<div class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog " >
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table table-bordered>
                     <thead>
                         [........]
                     </thead>
                     <tbody style="overflow-y:auto; height:400px; position:absolute>
                     [.......]
                     </tbody>
                   </table>
```

[...the rest of the `</div>`s...]

---

### EDIT

Thanks for the responses. Is there a way to narrow down the scroll bar to the `<tbody>` alone so that the `<thead>` remains static?

Comment: Instead put style on the div with class panel-body as overflow-y:scroll;
height:200px; see demo below in answers.

Comment: Do you have a missing end quote on the table class in your source too, or is that just an artifact from cutting down the code here in the question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Wrap it in `table-responsive` and set a max-height:

```
.table-responsive {
    max-height:300px;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/S6MgKWqFvj

Comment: I checked out the code you shared. This seems to add a scrollbar for the entire panel. I'm looking to have it only for the table. Moving the ```table-responsive``` from panel to ```<tbody>``` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: we don't want scroll for table header

Comment: I'm going with implementing this as it is the cleanest way I've seen to circumvent the current issue. I've tried taking a dig at keeping the header static while body being scrollable but ran into resizing issues. I'm accepting this answer. If I find a better way of doing it, I'll post an answer here. Thanks @ZimSystem

Comment: If anyone else lands here wanting to scroll **horizontally** note that: _"Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables."_

Answer (score 7):

Here is the demo

```css
#collapse1{
overflow-y:scroll;
height:200px;
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible List with table</h2>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group with table</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  >
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Anil. Any way to have the ```<thead>``` static?

Comment: you can put style position  fixed or static.

Comment: @AnilPanwar, no that doesn't work. Fixed puts it over the middle of the table and static has no effect (on THEAD)

Answer (score 4):

Try It Once I have Given An Example To You Question

```css
table,tr,th,td{
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tbl-header{
  width:calc(100% - 17px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 17px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 17px);
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl-header">
<table style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
<tr>
 <th width="50%">1</th>
  <th width="50%">2</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
  </div>
<div style="width:100%;overflow:auto; max-height:100px;">
   <table style="width:100%;">
     <tr>
     <td width="50%">dsada</td>
       <td width="50%">dsadas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>dsada</td>
       <td>dsadas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>dsada</td>
       <td>dsadas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>dsada</td>
       <td>dsadas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>dsada</td>
       <td>dsadas</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>dsada</td>
       <td>dsadas</td>
     </tr>
    
    </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: Nice. So your approach is to have 2 tables basically, one that represents the ```<thead>``` and one that represents ```<tbody>```. I'll give this a shot and see if this works out. Although, I'd somehow prefer them to be a single table!

Comment: classic issue of the columns not lining up